# Why not resize and clear works in GotW 54?

Tags: c++, vector, deque, gotw

Referring to article [Gotw 54](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm) by HerbSutter, he explains about

1. The Right Way To "Shrink-To-Fit" a
   vector or deque and
2. The Right Way to Completely Clear a vector or
   deque

> Can we just use `container.resize()`
>   and `container.clear()` for the above task
>   or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two different things that a vector holds: `size` Vs `capacity`. If you just `resize` the vector, there is no guarantee that the capacity(how much memory is reserved) must change. `resize` is an operation concerned with how much are you using, not how much the vector capacity is.

So for example.

```
size     == how much you are using
capacity == how much memory is reserved
vector<int> v(10);

v.resize(5); // size == 5 but capacity (may or may) not be changed
v.clear()    // size == 0 but capacity (may or may) not be changed
```

In the end, capacity should not changed on every operation, because that would bring a lot of memory allocation/deallocation overhead. He is saying that if you need to "**deallocate**" the **memory reserved** by vector, do that.

Comment: I thought the capacity will also be changed :-(

Comment: Note that even if you resize the vector to a bigger size, the capacity may not change also, because there could be just enough memory to deal with the new(bigger) size.

Answer (score 3):

Neither resize() nor clear() work. The `.capacity()` of a vector is guaranteed to be at least as big as the current `size()` of the vector, and guaranteed to be at least as big as the `reserve()`d capacity. Also, this .`capacity()` doesn't shrink, so it is also at least as big as any previous `size()` or `reserve()`ation.

Now, the `.capacity()` of a vector is merely the memory it has reserved. Often not all of that memory cotains objects. Resizing removes objects, but doesn't recycle the memory. A vector can only recycle its memory buffer when allocating a larger buffer.

The swap trick works by copying all ojects to a smaller, more appropriate memory buffer. Afterwards, the original memory buffer can be recycled. This appears to violate the previous statement that the memory buffer of a vector can only grow. However, with the swap trick, you temporarily have **2** vectors.

Answer (score 1):

The vector has size and capacity. It may hold X elements but have uninitialized memory in store for Y elements more. In a typical implementation erase, resize (when resizing to smaller size) and clear don't affect the capacity: the vector keeps the memory around for itself, should you want to add new items to it at a later time.